# VS 2017 Mage.exe with YubiKey

Tags: clickonce, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, yubikey

I am using VS 2017 to create an MS word Add in.  I am using clickonce(with a yubikey for signing) to publish the application.  I need to make a change to the application manifest file generated by clickonce which would require resigning several of the files.  My question is what parameters do I pass to mage.exe so that it will using the yubikey certificate?

Comment: I'm also trying sign my VSTO add-in with an EV code signing certificate (from Yubikey) so that it will be trusted instead of saying "unknown publisher". Hopefully the bounty will help.

Comment: @JstnPwll I figured out how to get my application signed with the Yubikey but it was not due to the manifest file being incorrect.  It was because I had multiple versions of Visual Studio installed on my machine.  I uninstalled all of them and I only have VS 2019.  That fixed my issue.

Comment: Hm. Maybe I just need to update VS, I'm still using 2015. I'm able to select my certificate to use for signing the manifests, but I'm not able to sign the assembly this way and when I try to install the VSTO it always says Unknown Publisher.

Comment: @JstnPwll That will probably do it.  But you will have to uninstall 2015.

Comment: That did indeed do the trick. If you want to create an answer suggesting an update to VS you can claim the bounty, I don't think SO will give it back to me anyway!

Comment: @JstnPwll I added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue due to having multiple versions of VS installed on my computer.  I uninstalled all versions of VS and installed VS 2019 and everything worked.